# Reading output from the forked process in the parent process

Tags: php, fork

I have a process in which I am forking a child process. Everything seems to be working fine, except I want to read the `stdout/stderr` in the parent process from which it was forked. Is there any way to do that?

From what I know, a forked process inherits the parent's file descriptors, including standard input and standard output so I tried to buffer the output and read it in the end using output buffering. Roughly, here is how it looks like:

```
ob_start();

$fork = pcntl_fork();

switch($fork) {
    case 0:
        echo "Child of: " . posix_getppid() . ". My Process ID is: " . posix_getpid() . PHP_EOL;
    break;
    case -1:
        echo "Forking failed!" . PHP_EOL;
    break;
    default:
        pcntl_wait($status); // store the child's exit status
        echo "I am parent with ID: " . posix_getpid() . ". My Child's ID is: $fork and it's exit status is:           $status" . PHP_EOL;
    break;
}

$output = ob_get_clean();

echo 'Process id – ' . posix_getpid() . PHP_EOL;
echo $output;
```

But the parent does not seem to be containing the output for the forked process. Why is the parent not containing the child processes output even though they share the parent's file descriptors? Is there any other way to achieve that?